# Default partition layout for debian 11

Tags: linux, debian

Having some issue resizing or adding new partition to Debian 11 I noticed some strange 1 megabyte partitions present on the system. Is this normal? The partition setting was not modified and default setting with LVM was used.

One of the issues for example I faced was using using `fdisk` to create new primary partition: it was assigning number 3, which was only 1 Megabyte. Any idea?

Layout:

```
parted /dev/sda print free

Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 17.2GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
        1024B   1049kB  1048kB            Free Space
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   primary   ext2         boot
        512MB   513MB   1048kB            Free Space
 2      513MB   17.2GB  16.7GB  extended
 5      513MB   17.2GB  16.7GB  logical                lvm
        17.2GB  17.2GB  1049kB            Free Space
```

Comment: do you mean the ~1 MB sections that are _not_ part of any partition, the ones marked "Free Space" in the parted output?

Comment: It almost looks like someone attempted to place the beginning of the first partition at 1MiB from the beginning of the disk, and likewise partition 2 {and 5) at exactly 512MiB from the beginning of the disk, probably for data alignment reasons... but perhaps `parted` rounds up and/or the original partitioner made a slight miscalculation.

Comment: @ilkkachu
Yup those one mega byte free spaces

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any significant space available for your use on the disk you've shown us. It's a 17GB disk and just about all 17GB is allocated across partitions 1, 2, and 5.

It's normal to have a 1MB partition at the beginning of a GPT disk and corresponding space at the end. There may also be small amounts of free space between partitions to allow them to align on a suitable sector boundary (at the least a multiple of 4kB, but often a multiple of 1MB).

There might be space in the 17GB Logical Volume (LVM) section (partition 5), but you would need to include the output of `pvs` and `lvs` in your question for us to help confirm that.

Comment: This was ouput from another machine more reagrding about those one megabytes free paritions.

Comment: Then this is impossible to answer with a practical suggestion - "_One of the issues for example I faced was using using fdisk to create new primary partition: it was assigning number 3, which was only 1 Megabyte. Any idea?_"

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is done to allow for a seamless upgrade of your partition table from MS-DOS to GPT.

The latter needs 1MB blocks in the beginning and end of the disk.

Comment: I was able to create new primary parition using parted and then add it to volume group to extend the lvm. also it seems there is not easy way to extend the / once it is mounted on lvm other than live booting or the method i used.